# Get day name from timestamp in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, select, timestamp

How do I get the day name from a timestamp datatype in MySQL?

`2013-01-01 15:00:28` should return `Tuesday`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
SELECT DAYNAME('2013-01-01 10:10:10');
```

Answer (score 6):

Short day name example. This will return 'Tue':

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2013-01-01 15:00:28','%a') as dayname;
```

Long day name example. This will return 'Tuesday':

```
SELECT DAYNAME('2013-01-01 15:00:28') as dayname;
```

Answer (score 3):

Or just format it with whatever language you are using.

lets say... PHP:

```
<?php

$date = '2013-01-01 15:00:28';
$datetime = new DateTime($date);
$formated_date = $datetime->format('l'); // Tuesday
```

lets say JavaScript:

```
var original_date = '2013-01-01 15:00:28';
var day_names = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
var date_object = new Date(x);
var formated_date = day_names[date_object.getDay()];
// alert or print formated_date
```